# Obexctl: Provide different result in terminal and script

Tags: bash, bluetooth, shell-script, expect, bluez

I have created a script where I want to send file over bluetooth. For that I took "obexctl" utility. I can transfer file using obexctl utility over terminal. But when I'm trying to incorporate the same in a script using expect, it says "Client proxy not available".

Can somebody help me with the code. Thanks in advance.

**Commands over terminal:**

```
$ obexctl

[NEW] Client /org/bluez/obex 

[obex]# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Attempting to connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

[NEW] Session /org/bluez/obex/client/session11 [default]

[NEW] ObjectPush /org/bluez/obex/client/session11 

Connection successful

[xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]# send abc.txt

Attempting to send abc.txt to /org/bluez/obex/client/session3

[NEW] Transfer /org/bluez/obex/client/session3/transfer1

Transfer /org/bluez/obex/client/session3/transfer1

        Status: queued
        Name: filename.sh
        size: 0
        Filename: abc.txt
        Session: org/bluez/obex/client/session3

[CHG] Transfer /org/bluez/obex/client/session3/transfer1 Status: complete

[DEL] Transfer /org/bluez/obex/client/session3/transfer1

[xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]#
```

**Shell Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
....
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
      set prompt "#"
      spawn sudo obexctl
      #expect -re \$prompt
      expect "Client"
      send "connect $hw_addr\r"
      sleep 4
      expect "Connection"
      send "send $bluetooth_log_file\r"
      send "quit\r"

EOF
....
```

On executing this script, it provides output as:

```
spawn sudo obexctl

[obex]# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Client proxy not available

[obex]#
```

The result should be same either executed manually on terminal or automated using a script.

Can somebody provide some suggestion where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don’t know anything about `obexctl`.  In your first code block, should I assume that everything ending with `#` is a prompt, everything *after* a `#` is user input, and everything else is program output?  If so, how does it know to say ``[NEW] Client /org/bluez/obex``?  Is that hard-coded in the program?  Do you have any idea why you go straight to the `[obex]#` prompt, without getting the ``[NEW] Client /org/bluez/obex`` message, when you run your script?  Do you maybe have an environment variable (or a config file) that tells it to use `/org/bluez/obex`?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Beware that ``sudo`` is probably stripping out environment variable.  (Why are you using ``sudo`` in your script when you don’t use it interactively?)

Comment: I'm also new to obexctl. Exploring it to use in script for transfering file over bluetooth. Using sudo or not, it was giving same result. And yes your all assumptions are right. And there is no hardcoded value. But that is the default behaviour of obexctl, it by-default uses `/org/bluez/obex`.  If there is any config file, I'll check and update here.

Comment: Moreover, when I check the path `/org/bluez/obex`, its not present directly in the system, looks like its a relative path. Because with this path, terminal is providing the correct result but not the script.

Comment: Also asked here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/516885/4667